# Android Studio/Java - Trouble with URLConnection and Receiver

Tags: java, android, url, connection

I am attempting to get when a file has last been modified on a server using the HttpUrlConnection class. If it has been modified more recently than a local file, the program will proceed with a download. However, I am having difficulties - there appears to be a problem with calling the getLastModified method.

```
    public class downloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private Context context;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

            long localUpdate;
            long remoteUpdate = 20;
            File dbFile = new File(c.getFilesDir(), "bk.db");

            localUpdate = dbFile.lastModified();
            try {
                Log.i("passing", "entering try");
                URL url = new URL("http://midamcorp.com/bk.php");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.i("passing", "con");
                Log.i("Database modified", "" + con.getLastModified());
                remoteUpdate = con.getLastModified();

                con.disconnect();

            } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("URL Exception:", "" + e.getMessage());}
     if(remoteUpdate > localUpdate) {
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) c.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Log.e("passing", "onReceive");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://midamcorp.com/bk.php"));
        request.setMimeType("application/octet-stream");
        manager.enqueue(request);
    } else {Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "No update necessary" + remoteUpdate + " " + localUpdate); }

        }


    }
```

The remoteUpdate value is never changed, an Exception message is never logged, and Studio logs "entering try" and "con" successfully, but then skips to logging the "No update necessary" statement.

```
04-08 12:02:30.096 2293-2293/midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp I/passing: entering try
04-08 12:02:30.159 2293-2293/midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp I/passing: con
04-08 12:02:30.166 2293-2293/midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp I/class midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.downloadReceiver: No update necessary20 1460134911000
```

Why might this be?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you added INTERNET permission in Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have. Thanks.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you supply a file name to the server. So of which file should it give the last modified time? I think you should read the documentation about that function.